# How to Redirect from PHP page by call of ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to redirect to welcome.php by sending ajax request to n.php. But It returns me all the code of  welcome.php how to fix this problem using php only.

```
<input type = "text" class="myname">
<input type = "submit" class="ok">

 $(".ok").on("click", function(e){
  var do = $('.myname').val();
    $.ajax({url: "n.php",
    cache: true,
    type: "POST",
    data: {moo:do},
    success: function(d){
      alert(d);
    }
   });
  });
```

In n.php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['moo']) ){
     if ($_POST['moo'] == "Nirikshan"){
     header('location: ../welcome.php');
     }else{
     echo"You Are Not Nirikshan";
     }
 }
?>
```

when I try to redirect to next page then alert box shows  all the html codes of page welcome.php how can i redirect to welcome.php by php only

Comment: You can't redirect a user with PHP using ajax. You need to redirect the user with JS. Just return the url and do: `location.href = d;` in the ajax success callback.

Comment: @nirik shan What is moo ?  in php code.

Answer (score 2):

Just put redirect on your jquery success,

like this,

```
success: function(d){
  if(d === true){
    window.location.replace("welcome.php");
  }
}
```

Replace your `alert(d)` with this code.

PHP page will be like,

```
<?php
if(isset(moo)){
       return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
   if(isset($moo))
   {
       echo true;
   }
   else
   {
       echo false;
   }
?>
```

Ajax:

```
success: function(response){
    if(response === true)
    {
        window.location('URL');
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `if(isset(moo))` ?

Comment: Sorry its $moo;

Comment: or may be `$_POST['moo']`

Comment: ya if if its value is not available in $moo;